# Debian home directory permissions get resetted

Tags: linux, debian, home-directory

On Debian Squeeze once a day the home directory permissions of one specific user get resetted to chmod 700 and chown root:root. Every day I have to set the permissions manually to login properly. Anyone got an idea where this comes from?

Comment: What's the name of the user? Maybe it is a "special" name like "www-data" or something like that. Does it have a uid of less than 1000?

Comment: Is the home directory in `/home/`?

Comment: Look at `/etc/crontab`,`/etc/cron.(d|daily)/*`, `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/*`.  Are you sure you don't have anything setup to reset permissions?  Do you have a configuration management system like puppet|chef|etc updating things?

Comment: It's a custom user just to avoid root login. Yes it's in /home/ directory. I was hoping this may be a common problem or bug to avoid looking through all the cron scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Install `audit` package:

```
Name       : audit
Arch       : x86_64
Version    : 1.7.13
Release    : 2.el5
Size       : 898 k
Repo       : installed
Summary    : User space tools for 2.6 kernel auditing
URL        : http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/
License    : GPL
Description: The audit package contains the user space utilities for
           : storing and searching the audit records generate by
           : the audit subsystem in the Linux 2.6 kernel.
```

Set a watch on `/home/user` for auditing:

```
# auditctl -w /home/user/ -p war
```

When the permission changes, you can find out who did it by running:

```
ausearch -f /home/user/
```

Example output:

```
time->Fri Sep  7 01:13:03 2012
type=PATH msg=audit(1346955183.879:429844): item=0 name="/home/user/" inode=849480 dev=03:03 mode=040700 ouid=0 ogid=500 rdev=00:00
type=CWD msg=audit(1346955183.879:429844):  cwd="/root"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1346955183.879:429844): arch=c000003e syscall=90 success=yes exit=0 a0=1303b0b0 a1=1e8 a2=1e8 a3=1e8 items=1 ppid=17909 pid=25018 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts0 ses=4294967295 comm="chmod" exe="/bin/chmod" key=(null)
```